# Android Studio project not loading Gradle GUI plug-in

Tags: android-studio, gradle-plugin

I face this issue after restarting my MacBook where Android Studio complains about Gradle plug-in.

Here's the screenshot.

[image: Gradle GUI]

Answer (score 1):

Fix: Uninstall Gradle View plugin in Android Studio, restart Android Studio and reinstall it.